# How to get rows which have non-null values in both periods but doesn't exists in other document of same company?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database where there are different components with 'Current' & 'Historical' period values. 
These components can belong to different documents of same company.

My derived table after multiple joins is like this -

```
company_id       document_id       component_id      value      period
1000                   100             1              456      current
1000                   100             1              870      historical
1000                   100             2              67       current 
1000                   100             2              NULL     historical
1000                   200             2              67       historical
```

I want to get component_id '1' from above : **it has values in both current & historical for document_id '100' but it doesn't exists for document_id '200'**

Answer (score 1):

You could check for count(distinct) = 2 with HAVING

```
     select document_id, component_id, count(distinct period)
     from my_table  
     group by  document_id, component_id 
     HAVING count(distinct period)= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get component_id '1' from above : it has values in both current & historical for document_id '100' but it doesn't exists for document_id '200'

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select component_id
from t
group by component_id
having count(*) filter (where period = 'current' and document_id = 100) > 0 and
       count(*) filter (where period = 'historical' and document_id = 100) > 0 and
       count(*) filter (where document_id = 200) = 0;
```

Comment: Problem is that document_id where it doesn't exists is not known, so can't use  count(*) filter (where document_id = 200) = 0

Comment: @bhaskarindian . . . This is the question that you asked, quite explicitly.  And this answers it.  You should probably ask another question to clarify what you really want to do.